# Configure workspace in RCP app

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm working on a RCP project to build a modeller. Now I want to configure the workspace for my app, I found this [article](http://hexapixel.com/2009/01/12/rcp-workspaces) and just followed it. But when I call

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()
```

all it returned to me is a plash "/".

before made above call, I had configured my product running with argument like:

```
-os ${target.os} -arch ${target.arch} -nl ${target.nl} -consoleLog -data @noDefault
```

and set a workspace in start method of Application.java like:

```
Location instanceLoc = Platform.getInstanceLocation();
instanceLoc.set(new URL("file", null, "d:\\temp"), false);
```

I know I missed something but I can't figure it out. Please help me this.

Thank very much!

Comment: What is your question? - Could please clarify your problem?

Comment: Sorry Tom, my question is why getWorkspace().getRoot() return just a plash "/" to me while all I need is "D:/temp" as configured before?

Comment: You can't set the location programmatically in an RCP app.  Does your config.in specify `@noDefault` or `@none` ?

Comment: No Paul, Actually I have no config.ini in my project. I just configure it in my product build **Run configurations -> Arguments**. I solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation()` instead.

In general: The Workspace API is an abstraction of your filesystem, so it does not know anything about the details of your underlying system to store files, the highest element is the workspace-root.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I solved the problem base on your idea. It's my stupid trying to create some file (as resource) out of context of "project" object. Calling `projectObject.getWorkspace()` makes my function work as I expect. My new problem is handling resource "Project" in RCP App, but it's another story. Thank again!